# How to save selected Items to Qsettings from QListWidget, QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.7, qsettings

I am Using PyQt5 and Py3.7, I am trying to loop through all my Qlistwidgets and save their string data, but also save all selected items on that widget. I slightly modified the loop from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279125/python-pyqt4-functions-to-save-and-restore-ui-widget-values), but am having some trouble getting the selected items to save and restore using the listwidget array loop. I checked the docs but can't seem to understand how to add additional options into the array (such as save all selected items), from the Qt docs for SetArrayIndex, [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QSettings.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QSettings.setArrayIndex).

My listWidgets have selectionMode set to MultiSelection.
I am currently saving using this:

```
def save_list_data(self):
    self.settings = QSettings("data.ini", QSettings.IniFormat)
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(self):
        if isinstance(obj, QListWidget):
            name = obj.objectName()
            self.settings.beginWriteArray(name)
            for i in range(obj.count()):
                self.settings.setArrayIndex(i)
                self.settings.setValue(name, obj.item(i).text())
            self.settings.endArray()
```

And then restoring the listWidget data using:

```
def open_list_data(self):
    self.settings = QSettings("data.ini", QSettings.IniFormat)
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(self):
        if isinstance(obj, QListWidget):
            name = obj.objectName()
            size = self.settings.beginReadArray(name)
            for i in range(size):
                self.settings.setArrayIndex(i)
                value = self.settings.value(name)
                if value != None:
                    obj.addItem(value)
            self.settings.endArray()
```

This works fine for the data, but how can I get the selectedItems from the ListWidgets to save and restore as well?

Comment: I am using PyQt5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my solution take into account the following:

- Using the inspect module may be beneficial for other libraries, but for Qt the widget is not necessarily a member of the class so it is best to use the Qt introspection itself using findChildren.
- In the example you use, you are only saving the text but a QListWidgetItem can have more information associated with the roles such as background color, foreground color, etc. So instead I will use the QDataStream operator since this take and save takes the item information.
- I will use the "objectname/property" format to save the information since the same widget can have several properties that you want to save.
- To save the information of the selected items, it is only necessary to save the row.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.listwidget_1 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(
            objectName="listwidget_1", 
            selectionMode=QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection
        )
        listwidget_2 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(
            objectName="listwidget_2", 
            selectionMode=QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection
        )

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.listwidget_1)
        lay.addWidget(listwidget_2)

        self.read_settings()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.write_settings()
        super().closeEvent(event)

    def read_settings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings("data.ini", QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
        childrens = self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QWidget)
        for children in childrens:
            if isinstance(children, QtWidgets.QListWidget) and children.objectName():
                settings.beginGroup(children.objectName())
                items = settings.value("items")
                selecteditems = settings.value("selecteditems")
                selectionMode = settings.value("selectionMode", type=QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectionMode)
                children.setSelectionMode(selectionMode)
                # In the first reading the initial values must be established
                if items is None:
                    if children.objectName() == "listwidget_1":
                        for i in range(10):
                            children.addItem(QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(str(i)))
                    elif children.objectName() == "listwidget_2":
                        for i in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
                            children.addItem(QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(i))
                else:
                    stream = QtCore.QDataStream(items, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
                    while not stream.atEnd():
                        it = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
                        stream >> it
                        children.addItem(it)
                    stream = QtCore.QDataStream(selecteditems, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
                    while not stream.atEnd():
                        row = stream.readInt()
                        it = children.item(row)
                        it.setSelected(True)
                settings.endGroup()

    def write_settings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings("data.ini", QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
        childrens = self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QWidget)
        for children in childrens:
            if isinstance(children, QtWidgets.QListWidget) and children.objectName():
                settings.beginGroup(children.objectName())
                items = QtCore.QByteArray()
                stream = QtCore.QDataStream(items, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
                for i in range(children.count()):
                    stream << children.item(i)
                selecteditems = QtCore.QByteArray()
                stream = QtCore.QDataStream(selecteditems, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
                for it in children.selectedItems():
                    stream.writeInt(children.row(it))
                settings.setValue("items", items)
                settings.setValue("selecteditems", selecteditems)
                settings.setValue("selectionMode", children.selectionMode())
                settings.endGroup()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Plus:**

```py
import contextlib
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class SettingsManager:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.m_settings = QtCore.QSettings(filename, QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)

    @property
    def settings(self):
        return self.m_settings

    def read(self, widget):
        self.settings.beginGroup(widget.objectName())
        if isinstance(widget, QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView):
            selectionMode = self.settings.value(
                "selectionMode", type=QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectionMode
            )
            widget.setSelectionMode(selectionMode)
        if isinstance(widget, QtWidgets.QListWidget):
            items = self.settings.value("items")
            selecteditems = self.settings.value("selecteditems")
            # In the first reading the initial values must be established
            if items is None:
                self.read_defaults(widget)
            else:
                stream = QtCore.QDataStream(items, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
                while not stream.atEnd():
                    it = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
                    stream >> it
                    widget.addItem(it)
                stream = QtCore.QDataStream(
                    selecteditems, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly
                )
                while not stream.atEnd():
                    row = stream.readInt()
                    it = widget.item(row)
                    if it is not None:
                        it.setSelected(True)
        if isinstance(widget, QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
            rowCount = self.settings.value("rowCount", type=int)
            columnCount = self.settings.value("columnCount", type=int)
            widget.setRowCount(rowCount)
            widget.setColumnCount(columnCount)
            items = self.settings.value("items")
            if items is None:
                self.read_defaults(widget)
            else:
                stream = QtCore.QDataStream(items, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
                while not stream.atEnd():
                    it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                    i = stream.readInt()
                    j = stream.readInt()
                    stream >> it
                    widget.setItem(i, j, it)
                selecteditems = self.settings.value("selecteditems")
                stream = QtCore.QDataStream(
                    selecteditems, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly
                )
                while not stream.atEnd():
                    i = stream.readInt()
                    j = stream.readInt()
                    it = widget.item(i, j)
                    if it is not None:
                        it.setSelected(True)
        self.settings.endGroup()

    def write(self, widget):
        self.settings.beginGroup(widget.objectName())
        if isinstance(widget, QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView):
            self.settings.setValue("selectionMode", widget.selectionMode())
        if isinstance(widget, QtWidgets.QListWidget):
            items = QtCore.QByteArray()
            stream = QtCore.QDataStream(items, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
            for i in range(widget.count()):
                stream << widget.item(i)
            self.settings.setValue("items", items)
            selecteditems = QtCore.QByteArray()
            stream = QtCore.QDataStream(
                selecteditems, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly
            )
            for it in widget.selectedItems():
                stream.writeInt(widget.row(it))

            self.settings.setValue("selecteditems", selecteditems)
        if isinstance(widget, QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
            self.settings.setValue("rowCount", widget.rowCount())
            self.settings.setValue("columnCount", widget.columnCount())
            items = QtCore.QByteArray()
            stream = QtCore.QDataStream(items, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
            for i in range(widget.rowCount()):
                for j in range(widget.columnCount()):
                    it = widget.item(i, j)
                    if it is not None:
                        stream.writeInt(i)
                        stream.writeInt(j)
                        stream << it
            self.settings.setValue("items", items)
            selecteditems = QtCore.QByteArray()
            stream = QtCore.QDataStream(
                selecteditems, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly
            )
            for it in widget.selectedItems():
                # print(it.row(), it.column())
                stream.writeInt(it.row())
                stream.writeInt(it.column())
            self.settings.setValue("selecteditems", selecteditems)
        self.settings.endGroup()

    def release(self):
        self.m_settings.sync()

    def read_defaults(self, widget):
        if widget.objectName() == "listwidget_1":
            widget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
            for i in range(10):
                widget.addItem(QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(str(i)))
        elif widget.objectName() == "listwidget_2":
            widget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
            for i in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
                widget.addItem(QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(i))
        elif widget.objectName() == "tablewidget":
            widget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
            widget.setRowCount(10)
            widget.setColumnCount(10)
            for i in range(widget.rowCount()):
                for j in range(widget.columnCount()):
                    it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("{}-{}".format(i, j))
                    widget.setItem(i, j, it)


@contextlib.contextmanager
def settingsContext(filename):
    manager = SettingsManager(filename)
    try:
        yield manager
    finally:
        manager.release()


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.listwidget_1 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(objectName="listwidget_1")
        listwidget_2 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(objectName="listwidget_2")

        tablewidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(objectName="tablewidget")

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.listwidget_1)
        lay.addWidget(listwidget_2)
        lay.addWidget(tablewidget)

        self.read_settings()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.write_settings()
        super().closeEvent(event)

    def read_settings(self):
        with settingsContext("data.ini") as m:
            for children in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QWidget):
                if children.objectName():
                    m.read(children)

    def write_settings(self):
        with settingsContext("data.ini") as m:
            for children in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QWidget):
                if children.objectName():
                    m.write(children)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Does this method only work for static items?  My lists will always have different data in them. So the part to at your comment `initial values must be established`, would not work in my case. Any method around that and only identify selected items? Basically making a save/restore feature for data in listWidgets. Everything is there but the selections.

Comment: @Laylor010 I did not say that the items are static but must have an initial value. My solution works if in the execution of the application items are added dynamically.

Comment: Was able to get that to work, still a little confused with `children.objectName()` and the `children.addItem` section. Would something like this work for tableWidgets as well?

Comment: @Laylor010 If you do not tell me what your confusion is I can not help you, on the other hand I have created an example of how to implement the logic for QTableWidget

Comment: I'll review it further with the documentation, Thanks for the answer and the additional info for the TableWidgets.